# Hide content at page load with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html

Hi I made the following code to hide content when page load. but it shows the hidden content for some time before hiding. I don't want visitor to see the content at all even for a second.

What can I do?

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $('#orderbody').hide();
    $('#reset').hide();
    $('#orderside').hide();
});
```

Comment: You could use css instead of javascript.

Comment: If you use CSS it will not show.

Comment: css or not have it exist on page load, add it in with js when required

Comment: Keep in mind, anyone that knows how to press F12 can modify your stylesheet and make the content visible. Best not to have it on the page at all if it is important data.

Comment: Thank you fixed with css  display: none

Answer (score 2):

The reason that this is happening is because the content is loading before the javascript has had a chance to load and execute. `$(document).ready()` ensures that the DOM is loaded and ready before execution, which ensures that there are elements there for you to work on, but is also causing your delay.

Set the "`display:none`" attribute in the CSS for those elements instead of hiding them via JQuery:

```
#orderbody,
#reset,
#orderside {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Put this in your CSS (and take it out of the jQuery -

```
#orderbody, #reset, #orderside {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: What I am hiding is not sensitive data. I am just try to show content base on visitor choices. I have tried display none with css and use jQuery to show when condition is met like `$('#platform').change(function(){
           if ($('#platform option:selected').text()=="AM"){ 
         $('#orderbody').show();

});`  but it doesn't show the content with ID.

Comment: Without seeing your markup it would be hard to tell you why you're having an issue.

Comment: Ho It is working now my style sheet link was at the bottom of the page. it also work well will jquery script but using css provide batter result.